# Adjust position of an image in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The little code below generates a graphic, but notice from the image that the image is being generated at the bottom, however I would like this image to be plotted on the right side. I have inserted an image of how the image is being generated so far and also another image of the position I would like the image to be generated. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

function.test<-function(){
  
df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-04"),
       Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Wednesday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,0),
       DR01 = c(4,1,0), DR02= c(4,2,0),DR03= c(9,5,0),
       DR04 = c(5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,4,0),DR06 = c(5,4,0),DR07 = c(5,4,0),DR08 = c(5,4,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))



return(df1)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       uiOutput("mycode"),
                                     ),
                                     fluidRow(
                                       column(12,
                                              sidebarPanel(
                                                
                                                conditionalPanel(
                                                  condition = "output.mycode",
                                                  uiOutput('daterange'),
                                                  actionButton("reset", "Reset")
                                                  
                                                  
                                                )))), ),
                                   
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(10,
                                            
                                            mainPanel(
                                              tabsetPanel(
                                                tabPanel("Output", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
                                                )
                                              ),
                                            ))
                                   ))))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2",
              label = h4("Data"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = NA,
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code))
  })
  
  my <- reactiveValues(plot=NULL)
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(input$date2) & !is.null(input$code)) {
      my$plot <- plot(cars) 
    }else {
      my$plot <- NULL
    }
    my$plot
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    my$plot <- NULL
    updateDateInput(session, 'date2', value = NA)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'code', h4("Category"),choices= unique(df1$Category), selected=character(0))
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**How are you at the moment:**

[image]

**How I would like it to be:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one `sidebarPanel()` in your `sidebarLayout()`, and it must be at the same level than the `mainPanel()`, [see the docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html), as follows (no need to insert some `fluidRow()` either):

```
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # menus, widgets
    ),

    mainPanel(
      # plot
    )
  )
```

Full code from your example:

```
sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
   
   uiOutput("date"),
   uiOutput("mycode"),
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "output.mycode",
                uiOutput('daterange'),
                actionButton("reset", "Reset")               
              )),

        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Output", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
            )
          )
)))
```

EDIT:
Since a `sidebarPanel()` is meant to be used as a single column, if you want separate panels on the left you can use several `wellPanel()` in a `fluidPage()` layout:

```
fluidPage(
 fluidRow(
   column(4, "sidebar",
   wellPanel(
   uiOutput("date"),
   uiOutput("mycode")
   ),
   wellPanel(
   conditionalPanel(
     condition = "output.mycode",
     uiOutput('daterange'),
     actionButton("reset", "Reset")               
   )
   )
   ),
 
 column(8, "main",
   tabsetPanel(
     tabPanel("Output", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")
     )
   )
 ))
)
))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But notice that the reset button is not on the same sidebarPanel in the image I inserted, so I made two that was to separate the reset button. I need to leave the reset button separate

Comment: Yes but what's the point of separating it? On your second image they are in the same sidebarPanel.

Comment: That's just what I can't do. The second image was to show how I would like the output image.

Comment: I want to separate because I intend to enter other information that needs to be separate. I used the reset button as an example, but it will have other information

Comment: A sidebarPanel is meant to be a single column containing all the inputs. You can separate the inputs in several blocks with some horizontal rules (hr()) and titles. Or use [nested columns/rows](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) instead of the sidebarLayout.

Comment: If you really want separate grey blocks, use wellPanel instead of sidebarPanel, see my edited answer